# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the code which has some problem:

```
symbol_returns[i*num_samples + sample_iter] = tf.multiply(tf.cast(pos[i*num_samples + sample_iter], np.float32), y_[:,i])

daily_returns_by_symbol_ = tf.concat( [tf.reshape(t, [-1,1],1) for t in symbol_returns.values()])
```

But there is some error, and I have no idea how to solve it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neural_net_exec.py", line 129, in <module>
    daily_returns_by_symbol_ = tf.concat( [tf.reshape(t, [-1,1],1) for t in symbol_returns.values()])
  File "neural_net_exec.py", line 129, in <listcomp>
    daily_returns_by_symbol_ = tf.concat( [tf.reshape(t, [-1,1],1) for t in symbol_returns.values()])
  File "/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2619, in reshape
    name=name)
  File "/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 374, in apply_op
    with g.as_default(), ops.name_scope(name) as scope:
  File "/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4522, in name_scope
    with g.as_default(), g.name_scope(n) as scope:
  File "/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3171, in name_scope
    if not _VALID_OP_NAME_REGEX.match(name):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: You'll have to provide more details on how your data looks. For e.g. what is in symbol_returns ? Often, it is the case that this variable is empty or has data of a different type.

Comment: I've provide the symbol_returns
Sorry for forgot it.

Answer (score 2):

The third argument to [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape), which is optional, should be a string; you have used an integer (i.e., `1`) as the third argument to `tf.reshape`, hence the error message.